# how to jump from one directory to another on the unix path

Tags: unix

How to jump from one slash to another in unix terminal instead of using arrow keys

i.e.
path 
/home/user/aa/bb/cc/dd/asdas/adsa/asdsa/adas/adas/adda/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Alt + F` to go forward and `Alt + B` to go backawards in a path.